# Force a string to be interpreted as a list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've got a data object that was created by creating what I assume is a json object -

```
jsonobj = {}
jsonobj["recordnum"] = callpri
```

and then pushing that onto a list, as there is more than one of them -

```
myList = []
myList.append(jsonobj)
```

Then that gets passed back and forth between flask subroutines and Jinja2 templates, until it ends up a few steps later coming into the function where I need to access that data, and it comes in looking something like so -

```
techlist: [{'recordnum': '1', 'name': 'Person 1', 'phonenumber': '123-456-7890', 'email': 'person1@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}, {'recordnum': '2', 'name': 'Person 2', 'phonenumber': '098-765-4321', 'email': 'person2@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}, {'recordnum': '3', 'name': 'Person 3', 'phonenumber': '567-890-1234', 'email': 'person3@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}]
```

I tried a `for tech in techlist: print(tech['recordnum'])` type deal and got an error, so I started printing types for everything and it's all strings.  The `for tech in techlist` is I think just splitting it all into words even, which is obviously not what I want at all.

I tried messing around with json.loads on techlist, but it complained about expecting an entry in double quotes or something along those lines.  I'm totally stumped, and would really appreciate if someone could please tell me how to turn this string back into a list of dicts or a list of json objects, or whatever it takes for me to be able to iterate through the items and access specific fields.

**Response to comments about it working right:**

It's coming in as a string for me, and I think for the two of you it is working for, you're creating it as a list, so it would work correctly ... sadly, that's my problem, it's a string, not a list, so it's doing this -

```
(env) [me@box directory]$ cat test.py
techlist = "[{'recordnum': '1', 'name': 'Person 1', 'phonenumber': '123-456-7890', 'email': 'person1@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}, {'recordnum': '2', 'name': 'Person 2', 'phonenumber': '098-765-4321', 'email': 'person2@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}, {'recordnum': '3', 'name': 'Person 3', 'phonenumber': '567-890-1234', 'email': 'person3@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}]"

print(type(techlist))

for tech in techlist:
  print(type(tech))
  print(str(tech))
(env) [me@box directory]$
(env) [me@box directory]$
(env) [me@box directory]$ python test.py
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
[
<class 'str'>
{
<class 'str'>
'
<class 'str'>
r
<class 'str'>
e
<snip>
```

**Update:**

Trenton McKinney 's comment worked PERFECTLY, THANK YOU!!  If you're so inclined as to post it as a answer I'll accept it as the solution.  Thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json object" in Python. What you have is a dictionary and you are constructing a list of dictionaries. You must be converting this to a string somewhere in your code if you are getting strings.

Comment: @Hyacin  :Can you please add the exact error message you are getting on screen, because what you have given works for me as sayandip mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert the string back to `dict`:

- Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate the string

```py
from ast import literal_eval

techlist = """[{'recordnum': '1', 'name': 'Person 1', 'phonenumber': '123-456-7890', 'email': 'person1@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'},
            {'recordnum': '2', 'name': 'Person 2', 'phonenumber': '098-765-4321', 'email': 'person2@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'},
            {'recordnum': '3', 'name': 'Person 3', 'phonenumber': '567-890-1234', 'email': 'person3@company.tld', 'maxnumtechs': 'ALL'}]"""

print(type(techlist))

>>> <class 'str'>

techlist = literal_eval(techlist)

print(type(techlist))

>>> <class 'list'>

print(techlist)

# output

[{'email': 'person1@company.tld',
  'maxnumtechs': 'ALL',
  'name': 'Person 1',
  'phonenumber': '123-456-7890',
  'recordnum': '1'},
 {'email': 'person2@company.tld',
  'maxnumtechs': 'ALL',
  'name': 'Person 2',
  'phonenumber': '098-765-4321',
  'recordnum': '2'},
 {'email': 'person3@company.tld',
  'maxnumtechs': 'ALL',
  'name': 'Person 3',
  'phonenumber': '567-890-1234',
  'recordnum': '3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Top answer are about string, but option 3 is about dealing with dictionaries with pandas

## Option 1

```
from csv import reader
import pandas as pd
data=[str]
df=pd.DataFrame( list(reader(data)))
print(df)

results = df[col].to_list()
```

## Option 2

Other wise just split str by a value

```
result = str.split(',')
```

## Option 3 (I am pretty sure this what you want):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(techlist)

results = df['recordnum'].to_list()
```

Hopefully one of those answer is good enough, cause your question is confusing

Comment: This may have worked, I'm not sure, I tried Trenton McKinney's answer from above and it did work, perfectly.  I tried to try your option 3, but simply importing pd gives me a "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" from "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pd/pdd.py", line 18" :-/ ... thanks though!!

Comment: Ok, I realized I needed to install pandas and then 'import pandas as pd', but I'm running into the same issue as where people above are saying it's working as-is ... your Option 3 works on a list of dicts, but NOT on a string, and my problem was that it was a string ... when I try to feed it a string I get -

    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!